# How to predict test data after adding polynomial features?

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression

I am creating polynomial features using a house prices dataset. But after adding these features to my train set, X_train don't fit the X_test no longer.

X_train shape: (17290, 18)
After adding new features,
X_train shape: (17290, 22)

But my X_test shape is still (4323, 18). I got error while predicting the test values. So what should I do after adding some polynomial features?

Answer (score 1):

Your model has changed and it looks like your still plugging in the same number of features before you added the features to your prediction array.

```
myarraytest = np.array(sampledata)
testdata = myarraytest.reshape(1,len(myarraytest))
reg.predict(testdata) #your model name
```

You should add the 4 new feature to the array your predicting so that the shapes are the same.

Comment: I added these new features just for improve the accuracy. In this data, that will not problem if I reshape my test set. But first question: what should be the values in these new added columns? And is there a way to don't add new columns to test set? Thanks.